# Do local db writes happen synchronously or asynchronously?

Tags: firebase

New to firebase and trying to understand how things work.  I have an android app and plan to use the offline support and I'm trying to figure out whether or not I need to use callbacks.  When I make a call like:

```
productNode.child("price").setValue(product.price)
```

Does that call to setValue happen synchronously on the main thread and the sync to the cloud happens asynchronously?  Or does both execute asynchronously on a background thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase client immediately updates its local copy of the data with the new value. As part of this it fires any local (`value`, `child_*`) events that are needed.

Sending of the data to the database happens on a separate thread. If you want to know when this has completed, you can register a [`CompletionListener`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-callback).

If the server somehow cannot complete the write operation (typically because the write violates a security rule), the client will fire any additional events that are needed to get the app back into the correct state. So in the case of a value listener it will then fire a second `value` event with the previous value.